# How to integrate Typed.js with Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typedjs

I would make a Typewriter effect in angular 2 using Typedjs

As indicated the [site](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) page, I have installed the package with npm :

```
npm install typed.js
```

Then I have added this code to my component :

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';// not sure if it's the right way
```

and

```
ngOnInit() {


    var typed = new Typed(".element", {
        strings: ["This is a JavaScript library", "This is an ES6 module"],
        smartBackspace: true // Default value
    });
}
```

Then in my html file :

```
<div id="typed-strings">
    <p>Typed.js is an <strong>Awesome</strong> library.</p>
    <p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
</div>
<span id="typed"></span>
```

I get this error :

`/home/haddad/projects/siteperso/src/app/slide-presentation/slide-presentation.component.ts (18,21): Cannot find name 'Typed'.`

PS: i'm open to any other proposition that do the same job as Typed.js and work with Angular 2/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `import` to import `Typed` from the `typed.js` module like so:

```js
import { Typed } from 'typed.js';
```

Answer (score 17):

Install typed.js package in your project

```
npm install typed.js --save
```

Import typed.js in your component.ts file

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';
```

Add this code in ngOnInit() of component.ts

```
const options = {
     strings: ['Innovation.', 'Discovery.'],
     typeSpeed: 100,
     backSpeed: 100,
     showCursor: true,
     cursorChar: '|',
     loop: true
};
    
const typed = new Typed('.typed-element', options);
```

Create html element to render output of typed.js

```
<span class="typed-element">Fsfsfsfsfs</span>
```

Comment: problem  is I can't create two elements using typedjs stupid af! .. works for 1

Answer (score 9):

You need to change your import to `import * as Typed from 'typed.js';`

Answer (score 1):

In order to say `"new Typed"` you need a constructor, and for that you need to import like this the Library:

```
import Typed from 'typed.js/src/typed.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in NPM that you can use. And it is quite simple

PACKAGE URL AND DOCUMENTATION
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-typed-js

COMMAND

```
npm install --save ngx-typed-js
```